# Redirect to another directory if url match pattern htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have WordPress installation with a subdirectory has the same name as the page. I rename this directory and I want to redirect to it whenever a specific URL has been requested.

In my wordperss I have >>> `/resources` path and I have
`/resources/page1`
`/resources/page2` etc

I also have a subdirectory called `resources` and have subdirectories called `page1` and has a `file1.zip` file.

I need whenever the user asks for `/resource/page1` to open it from WordPress and whenever the user asks for `/resource/page1/file1.zip` to download it from the directory. This subdirectory can have multi subdirectories, eg. `/resources/page1/releases/v1/file1.zip`

I am fine with renaming the subdirectory as long as I can handle the redirection.

I tried these rewriting conditions but unfortunately, I don't understand them properly.
In the .htaccess of the main WordPress I added

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^resources/([^/]+/.+)$ /resources1/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

but this rewriting it's not working

Comment: You mean, you have `/resources/page1` as a post/page slug inside your WordPress, but you also have `/resources/page1` existing as a physical directory? (That should not really work together in the first place, the WP routing does not interfere with any requests that match existing files or folders.)

Comment: If you configure rewriting on .htaccess level, then `RewriteRule ^/…` will never match; the leading slash has been stripped off of the path at this point already.

Comment: And your RewriteCond checks against `$1`, that is the first captured match from your RewriteRule here (if that was actually working, the mentioned leading slash issue aside.) So if the user requested `/resource/page1/file1.zip`, that would be `page1/file1.zip` here, and now you are trying to check if that matched `^/resources/(.*)`.

Comment: wordpress route to the physical directory, so I renamed it to resource1 and now it's not complaining, but I can't access the downloaded file from there. that's why I need redirection rule

Comment: If `resources/page1` is supposed to be a WordPress page, then you don’t want to redirect anything matching `resources/(.*)`, because that would include that page slug. You want to demand at least one additional folder level here. Try `RewriteRule ^resources/([^/]+/.+)$ /resources1/$1 [R,L]`, and without any RewriteCond.

Comment: No it didn't work

Comment: I updated it in the question, plz take a look

Comment: You need to put this _before_ the general WP rewriting, because that will pass all URLs that do not match any physically existing file or folder, to the index.php already.

Comment: OMG finally it works, thank you soooo much for ur help, can u plz add an answer and if u don't mind can u explain this regex `([^/]+/.+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WP default routing will rewrite all requests that do not match a physically existing file or folder, ot its own index.php - so you need to do your additional rewrite *before* this WP stuff.

And you can not match just `resources/(.+)` here - because you have `/resources/page1` as an existing WordPress page, and that one you don’t want to rewrite.

So demand at least one additional “folder” after `resources/` first.

```
RewriteRule ^resources/([^/]+/.+)$ /resources1/$1 [R,L]
```

`[^/]+` means, one or more characters out of the negated characters class `[^/]` first - that matches any character *but* a `/`.

By demanding an additional `/` after that, we have made sure, that we match at least one additional folder below `resources/`.

And then `.+` matches one or more arbitrary characters again, including slashes, so that you can have `foo.zip` or `bar/foo.zip` or even `bar/baz/foo.zip` after that.